# NServiceBus and wcf ServiceHost

Tags: wcf, nservicebus, servicehost

I have a wcf ServiceHost which has to publish a message to the IBus.

How do I gracefully gain access to the IBus from the host class (which is instatiated by wcf)?

Comment: Stig, are you hosting your WCF service inside NServiceBus.Host.exe?

Comment: yes I am hosting wht wcf in NServiceBus.Host.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we do (there may be a cleaner way) is we have a class that implements IWantToRunAtStartup. We give that class an IBus property that gets initialized by the DI container built into NServiceBus.

Then we instantiate our Web service class (the one that has the ServiceBehavior attribute), passing in the IBus instance from the start-up class. Then we instantiate our ServiceHost from that instance.

It feels a little kludgy, but we haven't had any trouble with it. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, had missed the point that a wcf service can be instantiated with an instance.

Answer (score 2):

This should provide access to the IBus for you a bit more cleanly.  Name the static class whatever you want.  Don't worry about sharing the IBus instance - the bus is fully thread-safe.

```
public static class BusAccess
{
    private static IBus bus;

    public static IBus Bus
    {
        get
        {
            if (bus == null)
                bus = NServiceBus.Configure.Instance.Builder.Build<IBus>();
            return bus;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No less testable than the IBus interface.  This is filled with whatever implementation is configured in the DI container, it is just providing you access to it within the WCF-instantiated class.  For testing, create a TestableBus class that implements the IBus interface and configure that on your test startup. Then this BusAccess class will give the code under test access to that.