# Doing NServiceBus publish from WCF service

Tags: wcf, nservicebus, publish

I have gone through the blog [NServiceBus and wcf ServiceHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011580/nservicebus-and-wcf-servicehost) where it talks about having a WCF service acting as publisher and publishing the events.

In my service implementation class I inherited  IWantToRunAtStartup interface and defined Start and Stop methods. But getting null exception on trying to IBus property as it is not getting injected. Can someone provide pointers on resolving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A stacktrace or code sample would be nice!